# Mongoose, change boolean value after time

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose in my ExpressJS webapp and I wanted to change some boolean value in schema, after some time.
Trying to use "expires" - but instructions say that it is only for Date values. 
What else can I do?

```
   var someSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       isactive: { type: Boolean, default: true}
   });
```

Comment: "expires" isn't a feature either Express or Mongoose/MongoDB offer natively. What instructions are you following?

Comment: @lagginingreflex http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_date_SchemaDate-expires i meant this.

Comment: MongoDB's TTL support can't be customized in this way. You'll have to do it in your own code.